# Find the conditional distribution of $(x_2, x_3),$ given $x_1$

Tags: multivariate-analysis, conditional-distribution

If we let $x∼N_3(\mu, \Sigma)$ with $\mu^T=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3)$ and $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma ^2&\sigma ^2\rho &\sigma \:^2\rho \:\\ \sigma \:^2\rho \:&\sigma \:^2&\sigma \:^2\rho \:\\ \sigma \:^2\rho \:&\sigma \:^2\rho \:&\sigma \:^2\end{pmatrix}$.

How do I find the conditional distribution of $(x_2, x_3),$ given $x_1$? (i.e. $(x_2,x_3|x_1)$)

I tried to use something like
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
x_2+x_3 \\
x_1
\end{matrix}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\ 1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\end{pmatrix}=AX$$
Which would then give
$$A\mu=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\ 1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mu _1\\ \mu _2\\ \mu _3\end{pmatrix}=\left(\begin{matrix}
\mu_2+\mu_3 \\
\mu_1
\end{matrix}\right)$$

And I would also need a covariance matrix in the form of
$$A\Sigma A'=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\ 1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\sigma ^2&\sigma ^2\rho &\sigma \:^2\rho \:\\ \sigma \:^2\rho \:&\sigma \:^2&\sigma \:^2\rho \:\\ \sigma \:^2\rho \:&\sigma \:^2\rho \:&\sigma \:^2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}=something$$

However, after this I am stuck and I am not sure if what I have done is correctly or what I should do next.

Comment: Begin by searching our site for [conditional normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional+normal+distribution).

Comment: @whuber that was of course my first thing to do. Asking a question is my last resort as stated in the rules. However I did not find anything that tackled this specific kind of question, and that is why I asked. I had already read everything in the links that was put in this thread, but I still did not understand. I am not sure I did it correctly and I am still unsure of my next step. I do not believe that this question should be closed as it is not a duplicate.

Comment: The question asked in the title is fully answered in the duplicates (and many other posts here on CV).   Merely applying a formula in a special case is rarely considered to be a new question.  Thus, you will need to be more explicit about what aspect of this question you are concerned about and what kind of answer you would be looking for.